# Future.get() not returning all the results

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, future

I am creating, say, 15 Callable tasks, and submitting them:

```
List<Future<MyResult>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<MyResult>>();
List<MyResult> myResults = new ArrayList<MyResult>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
    Callable<MyResult> task = new MyProcessor(//parameters);
    Future<MyResult> future = executorService.submit(task);
    futures.add(future);//used to iterate over to call get() to collect results in next for loop
}
```

Then I am collecting the 15 MyResult objects:

```
for(Future<MyResult> future : futures){
  try {
    MyResult myResult = future.get();
    processorResults.add(myResult);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      //...
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      //...
    }
}
```

Issue is: Instead of getting ALL 15 MyResult objects back from the get() method, I am sometimes getting less than 15 objects back. Sometime 12 sometimes 10 sometimes even lesser, and sometimes all 15.

I was under the impression that `get()` method is a blocking call and will wait for ALL 15 threads to get back with respective results, but looks like I miss a few of them and move ahead.
What is it that I am doing wrong? Am I not collecting the results/ waiting for the results correctly? Does this happen when an ERROR is thrown from any of the MyProcessor task?

Comment: Probably propagating an exception. Print out the stacktrace of ExecutionException

Comment: Just for the record: get() is blocking :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could mean that some of your jobs threw an exception.  It is hard to tell from your code but you need to do something with `ExecutionException` other than catching and ignoring it.

`Future.get()` throws `ExecutionException` when the `Callable` you submitted throws a `RuntimeException` from the `call()` method.  It will only return your `MyResult` if the method returns normally with `return`.  You can get the exception that was thrown by doing:

```
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // account for the throw here, the original exception is in e.getCause()
    // log it, count it, or ...
    logger.error("Job threw exception: " + e.getCause());
}
```

> I was under the impression that get() method is a blocking call and will wait for ALL 15 threads to get back with respective results,

This is correct.  When you call `future.get()` that will block until the job either finishes -- either by throwing an exception or returning.  If the thread that is going the `get()` is interrupted then the `get()` throws an `InterruptedException` which also should be caught and not just ignored.

Comment: So if 4 out of 15 threads throw an exception, then I would lose 4 MyResult objects? That means I would get the MyResult objects back only from successful threads?

Comment: Right @Kumar.  If the `call(...)` method returns naturally then you will get a `MyResult`.  If it throws an exception then the `get()` will throw `ExecutionException`.

Comment: Indeed, I was getting some `ClassCastException` which somehow found its way upto the get() method. Looks like now I have a lead to follow and can close the case soon. Thanks Gray John, Jonas.